# ValueError in seaborn scatterplot with hue argument

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, valueerror

I have been using sns.scatterplot for a while to plot my pandas dataframe, when suddenly it started trowing a

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

whenever I try to use the 'hue' or 'style' parameters.

The only thing I believe to have changed between then (when everything worked) and now is that I have updated all packages (conda). I believe that it has nothing to do with my data (like empty columns), since it works fine with a matplotlib scatterplot and the error is also thrown when I try the basic example on the seaborn documentation page:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time",
                     data=tips)
```

I cannot find anything related to this error message and the packages I use in the usual forums, which is rare. Other users seem to get this error message in very different situations.

Has anyone run into this? How is this error related to seaborn (but not to matplotlib)?

Comment: Maybe check whether you have the latest matplotlib, numpy and seaborn versions installed?

Comment: Good point. However, I believe it started happening right after updating (with conda update --all) and I have since re-updated (with conda update anaconda) and I also manually cross-checked the versions with those on the anaconda packages site.